# Angular 7 gives 404 on my html when navigating component path

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

We are converting some of the standard .net MVC pages from razor to Angular. Ive transitioned the data source, but now i need to get the new angular component to show in place of the old razor page. ive created a simple angular component but it's showing a 404 when i route to it's URL

http://localhost:51372#/systemdashboard/datatable

ive tried renaming the html page and it's showing the up to date file name in the 404, so i know its attempting it correctly. It seems like it just simply cant find the directory or something.

I have, however, added this component correctly to the app.module.ts as an import, declaration, router path, and provider

I've tried changing up the html name also to just make sure it's tryig to

here is my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-table',
    templateUrl: 'data-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
```

here is the errors:

GET http://localhost:51372/data-table.component.html 404 (Not Found)

unhandled promise rejection: failed to load data-table.componenet.html ; zone: >root> ; Task: Promise.Then ; Value: Failed to load data-table.component.html undefined

Comment: what is happening on that component?  I assume (from the name) that it's not just static?

Comment: Which route do you set for that component? The html template can't be accessible from path. You have to undestand that Angular has its own routing implementation.
https://angular.io/api/router/Route

Comment: You need a route in your router for this component otherwise there's no way angular know what's happening.

Comment: At this point it is literally just a <p>hello</> for the .html. the ts file is absolutely blank. no logic or anything is going into it. @myugen are you referring to inputting the pathing into the app.module.ts? if so, i have done the imports, declaration, router path and provider to include my component.

Comment: at this very moment, i deleted and re created the files. i literally copy/pasted the same exact code into each file and now somehow it works perfectly. i dont want to accept that as a viable option though. :/